# How to store all Modifiers/Editors of a SharePoint list item in a variable using Power Automate Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, append-changes

I am trying to append each person who have modified a SharePoint list item to a variable, so there is a record of all Modifiers and I can use that variable in emails and Microsoft Teams posts. I am new to Flow and Power Automate and I can't seem to be able to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would completely answer your question, as I don't know which fields are being updated in the SPList.

PowerAutomate:

Trigger: When SPList is updated

Send Email(?) with field: Modified By.
That is, if you want to received multiple emails every time the list gets updated.

PS There are other ways to do this with the Multi-line Text Column, however, you seem to want to send this information out of SP. You could also explore the native "Alert" feature in SPLists. [How to set alerts on SPLists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-notifications-on-for-list-and-list-item-changes-85ca9280-f4b1-485a-a49e-a593ffa62e39)